# parent div height are smaller than expected

Tags: html, css

I am practicing on web design and I noticed that the height of the parent div is somehow smaller than the child div.

[image]

here is my css code:

```
html,body{
    background-color: #ecf0f1 ;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


#homeDisplay{
    width: 850px;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid #7f8c8d;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:8px;
}

#signupForm{
 text-align: right;
    float:right;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid #7f8c8d;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: It's because you are using `float:left`. Try setting `overflow: hidden` on the parent that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `float:right` for the inner content, so it is removed from the normal flow of the document and parent can't adjust it's size according to the content's size. Fix : set `overflow:auto` CSS property to the container.

Comment: I see float:right in the question for the inner content. Please edit the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the float: right in your #signupForm. This causes the div to be taken out of the floating of the document.

Put a

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

with

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

after the signup form.